# ng-click stops working when using ng-if

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pug

So I have a button called "show more" that will increase the number of items in a list once it reaches the maximum number of list I want to change to a button called "show less" which brings the list back to its default value.

I use an ng-if to determine which button to be shown and ng-click to determine the action. When using them together the ng-click stops working and nothing happens when I click.

here is the html I have written in jade, feedLimit is the number of items showing in the list.

```
button.btn.btn-primary.btn-block.btn-sm.btn-outline(type='button')(ng-if= "feedLimit < notifications.all.length", ng-click="feedLimit = feedLimit + 4")
  span(translate) Show More
button.btn.btn-primary.btn-block.btn-sm.btn-outline(type='button')(ng-if= "feedLimit >= notifications.all.length", ng-click="feedLimit = 4")
  span(translate) Show Less
```

I've tried using ng-show and ng-hide and they work fine but it is better to use ng-if, there is no animation and it is faster.

Here is the show more button's html output

```
<button type="button" ng-if="feedLimit < notifications.all.length" ng-click="feedLimit = feedLimit + 4" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm btn-outline ng-scope" style=""><span class="ng-scope">Show More</span></button>
```

Comment: I noticed you have a space after your `=` on your `ng-if`.  Maybe Jade is mis-interpreting the ng-if attribute?

Comment: Angular 1.2 doesn't appear to have any problems with having ng-if and ng-click on the same element.  http://jsfiddle.net/bgcgfnqr/1/

Comment: tried deleting the space no dice, also @JamesM.Lay you used a function which maybe making a difference.

Comment: Oh yeah, I looked right over that.  It definitely appears to be influencing the problem.  [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bgcgfnqr/5/)

Comment: Looks like you found a bug!  [evidence here](http://jsfiddle.net/bgcgfnqr/7/).  Maybe consider submitting a bug on the [angular issue tracker](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues)

Comment: do you think ng-switch would just as good of an idea as ng-if, or should i just make my own function?

Comment: Nope, doesn't appear to make a difference. [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/B3zmxNUbWRLMsxSqPCf0?p=preview).  I would try instead either avoiding inline functions for ng-click or wrapping your buttons in a <span> that holds the ng-if directive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: ng-if not working in combination with ng-click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812116/angularjs-ng-if-not-working-in-combination-with-ng-click)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your running into a common issue with angularjs and child scope inheritance.

You are data-binding to a primitive value and ng-if is creating a child scope. When your ng-click directive changes the value of 'feedLimit', you are actually creating a new 'feedLimit' property on the child scope but the ng-if directive is bound to the 'feedLimit' of the parent scope.

The solution is to avoid binding to a primitive value. Instead make sure you use dot-notation by binding to an object.

Instead of

```
<button ng-if="feedLimit < notifications.all.length" ng-click="feedLimit = feedLimit + 4">
```

try something like

```
<button ng-if="someObj.feedLimit < notifications.all.length" ng-click="someObj.feedLimit = someObj.feedLimit + 4">
```

Here is a more detailed explanation of whats going on.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't
>   even need to know it is happening... until you try 2-way data binding
>   (i.e., form elements, ng-model) to a primitive (e.g., number, string,
>   boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope. It
>   doesn't work the way most people expect it should work. What happens
>   is that the child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the
>   parent property of the same name. This is not something AngularJS is
>   doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works. New
>   AngularJS developers often do not realize that ng-repeat, ng-switch,
>   ng-view and ng-include all create new child scopes, so the problem
>   often shows up when these directives are involved. (See this example
>   for a quick illustration of the problem.)
>
> This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the
>   "best practice" of always have a '.' in your ng-models

Comment: The child scope seems to be causing the problem. I updated James' fiddle to use an object instead of a primitive and it works - http://jsfiddle.net/bgcgfnqr/8/

Comment: making it into an object feed.limit worked, thank you!

Comment: I found using ng-show instead got it working in a similar situation I had however @jcruz soloution looks like the best way to approach this.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation!