# ng-click not working with ng-if angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying  to toggle a `div` on button click like as bellow.

**This is working**.

```
<div>
    <button ng-click='x = ! x'>toggle</button>
</div>  
<div  ng-include="'pages/include/search.html'" ng-show='x'></div>
```

**This is not working**.

```
<div ng-if="$state.current.url!='/splash'" >
    <button ng-click='x = ! x'>toggle</button>
</div>  
<div  ng-include="'pages/include/search.html'" ng-show='x'></div>
```

Why it is not working, when I add `ng-if="$state.current.url!='/splash'"` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: ng-if not working in combination with ng-click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812116/angularjs-ng-if-not-working-in-combination-with-ng-click)

Answer (score 1):

Well,

**Every angular directive create new scope**

In the code below

```
<div ng-if="$state.current.url!='/splash'" >
   <button ng-click='x = ! x'>toggle</button>
  </div>  
 <div  ng-include="'pages/include/search.html'" ng-show='x'></div>
```

The **ng-if**  directive create new scope.And withing this scope
the value of **x** is updated on button click.But this new value of **x** is not accessible outside this **ng-if**  div as it is local to that scope and it is primitive type.
Since this **x** is primitive type so there is no data update as reference are differant.

You should use object model instead.

Here is the updated HTML

```
<div ng-if="$state.current.url!='/splash'" >
   <button ng-click='x.showHide = ! x.showHide'>toggle</button>
  </div>  
 <div ng-include="'pages/include/search.html'" ng-show='x.showHide'>This is div</div>
```

define **x**  like this one in your controller.

```
$scope.x = {showHide:false}
```

EDIT-

In your first woking HTML, there is not directive on div.So, both these DIV come under same scope.So,**x** accessible across this two DIV with updated value.

```
<div>
<button ng-click='x = ! x'>toggle</button>
</div>  
<div  ng-include="'pages/include/search.html'" ng-show='x'></div>
```

Comment: but if we use ng-show instead of ng-if its working. can you please explain more..

Comment: Can u please add plunker?