# angularJs ng-click is not working inside the ng-if function

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-if="quantity > 0">
 <button ng-click="quantity = quantity-1">-</button>
</div>
```

Above is my code. i dont know why the ng-click doesnt work when it shows up. anyone can give me advise? thanks.

Comment: what is your initial `quantity` value ?

Comment: Post your complete html and controller code as well.

Comment: please provide your `ngController` code where you assign `$scope.quantity`.

Comment: see the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tTqLYTW5lkiD6fzPRNxJ) its working correctly.

Comment: check the answer with the working fiddle.I hope it is as per expectation.

Comment: i am conditioning it that the quantity must NOT go lower than 0.. eg, -1 -2 -3

Comment: @KimSean i updated answer and fiddle as per your requirement. please check now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: ng-if not working in combination with ng-click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812116/angularjs-ng-if-not-working-in-combination-with-ng-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this it will work :**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-show="quantity > 0">
    <button ng-click="quantity = quantity-1">-</button>
    <p>{{quantity}}</p>
  </div>
</div>

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.quantity = 6;
});
```

**Working fiddle :**
http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8856/

Answer (score 1):

Angular has its own "Dot" rule.

If you keep the quantity stored in controller scope, you might try this inside controller:

```
$scope.myvar = {
    quantity: 2,
    decrease: function() {
        this.quantity--;
    }
}
```

and html

```
<div ng-if="myvar.quantity > 0">
 <button ng-click="myvar.decrease()">-</button>
</div>
```